# Extract columns from every six lines

Tags: file, awk, sed, filter

I have a file that looks like this:

```
194170,46.9,42.2
194170,47.7,40.0
194170,48.5,42.0
194170,48.6,43.0
194170,49.8,39.2
194170,50.2,43.3
194179,44.9,36.9
194179,45.3,36.3
194179,46.4,36.9
194179,47.5,34.4
194179,48.0,40.0
194179,49.6,37.1
194184,52.8,51.1
194184,52.9,49.8
194184,54.0,51.9
194184,56.8,54.9
194184,57.6,53.6
194184,57.8,52.9
...
```

For a given line, the first number is an ID, and the second and third number are what I'm interested in. For those lines with the same ID (that is, every six lines), the numbers in the same column are numbers for consecutive years. I want to end up with a file that looks like this:

```
194170,46.9,47.7,48.5,48.6,49.8,50.2
194170,42.2,40.0,42.0,43.0,39.2,43.3
194179,44.9,45.3,46.4,47.5,48.0,49.6
194179,36.9,36.3,36.9,34.4,40.0,37.1
```

That is, for lines with the same ID, I want to group the consecutive numbers from the second column together, and likewise with the third column.

Is this possible to do with awk/sed/others?

Comment: Excel can be one of "Others"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F',' '{ a[$1] = a[$1] ? a[$1] FS $2 : $2 ; b[$1] = b[$1] ? b[$1] FS $3 : $3}
   END { for(idx in a){ print idx,a[idx] ; print idx,b[idx]}}' yourfile
```

Explanation:

- `-F` Field separator
- `a[]` will have second column values
- `b[]` will have third column values
- `END{}` printing the values

Example:

```
$ awk -F',' '{ a[$1] = a[$1] ? a[$1] FS $2 : $2 ; b[$1] = b[$1] ? b[$1] FS $3 : $3}
   END { for(idx in a){ print idx,a[idx] ; print idx,b[idx]}}' yourfile
194170 46.9,47.7,48.5,48.6,49.8,50.2
194170 42.2,40.0,42.0,43.0,39.2,43.3
194184 52.8,52.9,54.0,56.8,57.6,57.8
194184 51.1,49.8,51.9,54.9,53.6,52.9
194179 44.9,45.3,46.4,47.5,48.0,49.6
194179 36.9,36.3,36.9,34.4,40.0,37.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer with awk:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' yourfile
```

For two columns:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2;b[$1] = b[$1]","$3}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]"\n"i b[i]}' yourfile
```

Anyway, I prefer tidyR in R for that kind of task.

Comment: this may not give expected output. 1) order may be missing 2) will have a leading comma (`a[$1] = a[$1]","$2`)

Comment: The order of the output will be indeterminate. If you have GNU awk, add this before the for loop: `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` ([ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html))

Answer (score 0):

Another awk version, which doesn't use arrays and maintains the original order (not using arrays could be an advantage if it's a very large file that you don't want to have to load all of into memory before printing --- otherwise, the array version is fine, assuming you don't care about the ordering).

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

!prev_id { prev_id = $1 }

$1 == prev_id { r1 = r1 OFS $2; r2 = r2 OFS $3 }

$1 != prev_id { print prev_id r1 ORS prev_id r2; 
                r1 = OFS $2; r2 = OFS $3; prev_id = $1 }

END { print prev_id r1 ORS prev_id r2 }


$ awk -f v3.awk file.txt
194170,46.9,47.7,48.5,48.6,49.8,50.2
194170,42.2,40.0,42.0,43.0,39.2,43.3
194179,44.9,45.3,46.4,47.5,48.0,49.6
194179,36.9,36.3,36.9,34.4,40.0,37.1
194184,52.8,52.9,54.0,56.8,57.6,57.8
194184,51.1,49.8,51.9,54.9,53.6,52.9
```